# Failed to list directory contents: process waits infinitely

Tags: directory, ls, lsof

I use Linux Mint 13, and sometimes (rarely) I find myself not being able to list my home directory contents. When I try to do so:

```
$ cd
$ ls
```

then, `ls` just waits indefinitely. The same with any other application when it tries to read directory contents: I have to kill that application eventually.

I have used this linux distribution for about a year, my machine is typically always on (24/7), and I first faced this issue a couple of weeks ago. Then, I just tried to close all applications, that didn't help, then I rebooted the machine, and it helped: problem was "fixed".

Today I faced it again. This time I tried to find a bit more about the reason: I googled `lsof`, tried to use it, but... it waits indefinitely, too! More, it waits even if I try to `lsof` any directory, not just home directory. Say, `$ lsof /path/to/any/file` causes `lsof` to wait indefinitely.

Just in case, I tried to use `lsof` on remote machine via ssh, it works. So, it seems like deeper problem on my local machine.

(I'm not going to reboot the machine now, I hope to catch the reason)

UPD: parts of `dmesg` output:

```
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288107] INFO: task lsof:32463 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288112] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288116] lsof            D c1044aa0     0 32463      1 0x00000084
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288122]  f10f3dc0 00000086 f10f3d68 c1044aa0 00000001 f3108ca0 c18e43c0 c18e43c0
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288132]  eea0a18a 0004a2af f45073c0 ee00a5e0 ed9c25e0 ee00a5e0 f10f3db4 f10f3d84
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288141]  c105be37 ee00a5e0 f10f3d9c c105c535 00000296 f10f3d9c f10f3d9c c1027378
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288150] Call Trace:
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288160]  [<c1044aa0>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x140/0x190
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288167]  [<c105be37>] ? recalc_sigpending+0x17/0x40
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288172]  [<c105c535>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x35/0x80
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288178]  [<c1027378>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x8/0x10
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288183]  [<c1576d2d>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x2d/0x40
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288188]  [<c1575135>] schedule+0x35/0x50
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288193]  [<c121755d>] request_wait_answer+0x6d/0x1f0
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288198]  [<c106a390>] ? add_wait_queue+0x50/0x50
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288203]  [<c1217758>] fuse_request_send+0x78/0xb0
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288208]  [<c121bd6c>] fuse_do_getattr+0x12c/0x280
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288213]  [<c113d80d>] ? complete_walk+0x7d/0x100
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288219]  [<c121c381>] fuse_update_attributes+0x41/0xa0
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288224]  [<c121c684>] fuse_getattr+0x44/0x50
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288228]  [<c11370e2>] vfs_getattr+0x42/0x70
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288233]  [<c121c640>] ? fuse_listxattr+0x130/0x130
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288237]  [<c113716c>] vfs_fstatat+0x5c/0x80
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288241]  [<c11371e0>] vfs_stat+0x20/0x30
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288245]  [<c1137456>] sys_stat64+0x16/0x30
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288251]  [<c100ceec>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x15c/0x170
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288256]  [<c1576ed4>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Nov 12 14:35:36 dimon-progr kernel: [1305000.288260]  [<c1570000>] ? encode+0x26/0x2b
```

Comment: Check your path and see if you are using the correct ls.

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg`. You might have a hardware problem. Hard-drive physical problems can cause those symptoms.

Comment: What filesystem are you running? How full is it?

Comment: @Anthon it's ext4, I have 5.4G free of 82G.

Comment: @LuisAntolin thanks for the suggestion, I've checked it: there are errors related to `lsof`, but nothing related to `ls` or hardware faults; I've added part of `dmesg` output to my answer.

Comment: Blocked in FUSE. What type of filesystem were you accessing? That's the “Type” column in the output of `df -T /path/to/the/file`. A disk error would result in errors about the disk in the kernel log, but a memory error wouldn't. Run a memory test (I think Mint offers that option at boot time, if it doesn't install the `memtest86+` and then select “memory test” at the boot prompt.

Comment: @Gilles, thank you! I can't check it because some time after it started to work again, but actually I use FUSE for remote file system: `sshfs` and `gvfs-mount`. It's surprising that they can block so hard if remote system becomes unavailable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processes attempting to access a filesystem block indefinitely if the filesystem driver never responds.

For a filesystem that is stored on a storage device, the main cause for not responding is that the underlying hardware is not responding or is faulty. This usually produces copious messages in the kernel logs (visible with `dmesg` on Linux or in the appropriate log file such as `/var/log/kern.log`), and eventually causes a timeout and an I/O error (EIO).

Network-backed filesystems might not respond because no response from the server is coming, which could be because the network is down, or the server machine is down, or the server program isn't running or configured properly. Depending on the filesystem type, on the driver and on its configuration, this can result in a timeout or in an infinite wait. NFS, in particular, defaults to an infinite wait: it's stateless (if the server goes down in the middle of an operation, the operation can resume when the server comes back), so clients block until the server responds (because if the server does come back eventually then the filesystem will behave correctly).

For FUSE filesystems, it's up to the program implementing the filesystem. FUSE is very flexible since it can be implemented by arbitrary programs. The reverse side of the coin is that sometimes FUSE filesystems aren't very robust internally or are dependent on a lot of other components that might misbehave.

If a filesystem isn't responding, first check what type of filesystem it is. On Linux, look for the mount point in `/proc/mounts`; the mount point is the second field and the filesystem type is the third field. This tells you where to look for more clues:

- For filesystems on a storage device, look in the kernel logs.
- For network-backed filesystems, check network connectivity and check if the server is responding. Relevant logs are typically in service logs (e.g. `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/daemon.log` or a log that's specific to the network service).
- For FUSE filesystems, check if the process is responding.

If you have processes blocked in I/O and you've given up on waiting for the filesystem to come back up, you may want to forcibly unmount the filesystem. If it's a FUSE filesystem, killing the process that provides it will do the trick. For any type of filesystem, on Linux, you can perform a “lazy unmount” with `umount -l`: this detaches the filesystem from its mount point, even if the filesystem driver is stuck; the driver keeps operating (e.g. it keeps communicating with the hardware if that's what it's doing).